# Why do I see an empty product in products.index?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

This is how my `products.index` looks:

[image]

When I click on "Create product" link. It sends me to `/products/new`. I see a form there, but I dont submit it, instead I click on the "Cancel" button. I have an action in my controller that redirects me to the `products.index` page.

```
  actions: {
    cancel: function() {
      this.transitionToRoute('products.index');

      return false;
    }
  }
```

In `/products`, I see:

[image]

Which is an empty product... The DB in the API has no products. I refresh the page, and the empty product goes away. Whats going on here?

The full code:

```
// app/routes/products/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('product');
  }
});

// app/routes/products/new.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('product');
  },
});

// app/controllers/select-addresses/new.js
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    cancel: function() {
      this.transitionToRoute('products.index');

      return false;
    }
  }
});

// app/templates/products/index.hbs
<h1>Products index</h1>

<p>{{#link-to 'products.new'}}Create product{{/link-to}}</p>

<ul>
  {{#each}}
  <li>
    {{#link-to 'products.show' this}}<strong>{{name}}</strong>{{/link-to}}
    <br />Description: {{description}}
    <br />Amount in cents: {{amountInCents}}
    <br />{{link-to 'Edit' 'products.edit' this}} &middot; <a href="#" {{action "delete" this}}>Delete</a>
    <br /><br />
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

// app/templates/products/new.hbs
<h1>Add a new friend</h1>

<form {{action "save" on="submit"}}>
  <p>
    <label>Name:
      {{input value=name}}
    </label>

    {{#each error in errors.name}}
      <br />{{error.message}}
    {{/each}}
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Description:
      {{input value=description}}
    </label>

    {{#each error in errors.description}}
      <br />{{error.message}}
    {{/each}}
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Amount in cents:
      {{input value=amountInCents}}
    </label>

    {{#each error in errors.amountInCents}}
      <br />{{error.message}}
    {{/each}}
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Status:
      {{input value=status}}
    </label>

    {{#each error in errors.status}}
      <br />{{error.message}}
    {{/each}}
  </p>

  <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
  <button {{action "cancel"}}>Cancel</button>
</form>

{{outlet}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ember-data-route](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-data-route) and then you should do

```
{{#each product in model}}
  {{#unless product.isNew}}
    {{product.name}}
  {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

If you don't want to use `ember-data-route`, you can always use [resetController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_resetController) and do `model.deleteRecord()`.

```
// app/routes/products/new.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('product');
  },

  resetController: function (controller, isExiting) {
    var model = controller.get('model');

    if (isExiting && model.get('isNew')) {
      model.deleteRecord()
    }
  }
});
```

For a more in-depth version see what ember-data-route [is doing](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-data-route/blob/master/addon/mixins/data-route.js#L5).

Answer (score 2):

My guess (as a non-Ember-specialist):

In your `Ember.Route.extend`, for the model, you issue a call to `store.createRecord`. By this you add an empty product to the store. When you cancel the form, you do not remove the dummy product from the store, so it is still there when you load the index view.

Comment: That is correct. One way around that is to use https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-buffered-proxy somewhere.

Comment: That's a sane guess. Where do you think `store.createRecord` be defined?

Comment: @Leeft surely this is quite a common issue then, if it is happening. Is there a way to get this going "normally" without having to install an external library? Perhaps there is an "ember way"?

Comment: You'd think that, yeah. The problem boils down to (a) wanting a fresh record from the model so your default values are set and (b) `.createRecord()` for achieving (a) unfortunately also pushes it to the store. It would need an ember-data API change to allow you to create a record but not push it to the store. You could filter the shown records by the `created.uncommitted` state, though I found the addon easier and more reliable. It also helps with an existing record not changing while you are editing.

Comment: Could you give out an example on how to filter records by `created.uncommitted`?

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Might be a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

So in the product index routes, I changed `return this.store.find('product');` to `return this.store.find('product', {});`

And the problem went away! I am not sure if this is the right approach, but so far no issues!

```
// app/routes/products/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // Before
    // return this.store.find('product');

    // After
    return this.store.find('product', {});
  }
});
```

---

UPDATE: Doing `this.store.unloadAll('product');` before the transition also seems to work. This seems to be a more natural solution. As per this pull request https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1714

However, clicking the back button on the browser, still renders the empty product.

So basically:

```
// app/routes/products/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('product');
  }
});

// app/controllers/select-addresses/new.js
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    cancel: function() {
      this.store.unloadAll('product');
      this.transitionToRoute('products.index');

      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `deactivate` route hook to delete the new (not-persisted) record from the store.

```
// app/routes/products/new.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('product');
  },
  deactivate: function () {
    var model = this.modelFor('products.new');
    if (model.get('isNew')) {
      model.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
});
```

When you transition away from the route without persisting the record with `.save()`, it will destroy the record in the store, and therefore won't be rendered in the template.